# Stop wordpress from grabbing post's featured image

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm no programmer, usually I'm able to figure out some simple code but not this time unfortunately. I have site built on custom wordpress theme and they programmed it the way that on individual post pages same image is displayed as the post's image and blog page's image, example here: http://krakow4us.com/christmas-in-krakow/ Blog page has another picture set already, as seen here http://krakow4us.com/blog/ and I would like it to keep using this picture.

Do you have an idea for a code I could add to functions.php on my Child theme that would make the post's page use the blog page's image instead?

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: please post some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: you will need to see in `single.php` for posts and `page.php` or any template if they have created for pages

Comment: and for blog page check index.php

Answer (score 1):

You can get the featured image of your posts overview page like this:

```
<?php
    $homepage_has_featured_image = has_post_thumbnail( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
?>
```